# How to solve the problem of processing a matrix and combining values with a second matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

I created a function that traverses the matrix and assigns values from the matrix b to them. First it passes the first row and the last column, then the second row and the penultimate column, and thus passes the whole array.

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import math
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)


def matrix_assing(a, b):
    output = []
    
    for i in range(len(a[0])):
        horizontal_values_to_assign = a[i][: len(a[i]) - i]
        vertical_values_to_assing = a.T[-(i+1)][i+1:]
        
        values_to_assign = np.append(horizontal_values_to_assign, vertical_values_to_assing,)
        
        output += list(zip(values_to_assign, b[i:len(b) - i],))
        
    return output

a = np.array([[11, 12, 13, 14,15,16,17],
              [21, 22, 23, 24,25,26,27],
              [31, 32, 33, 34,35,36,37]])
```

n takes the horizontal number of columns in the array
n=a.shape[1]
b takes the number of rows vertically
b=a.shape[0]
I calculate this by this formula which is fixed

```
helper=n-b+1
print(helper)
```

I will use the result for trimming the matrix

```
a=np.delete(a, np.s_[helper:], axis=1)
b = np.array([100,200,300,400,500,600,700],)
```

then I apply the function to the matrix

```
c=str(matrix_assing(a, b))
c=str(c).replace(")",'\n')
c=str(c).replace("]",'')
c=str(c).replace("[",'')
c=str(c).replace("(",'')
c=str(c).replace(",",'')
c=str(c).replace("\n ",'\n')
print(c)
```

my output

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    
      File "C:\Users\Pifko\dp\pigeon_hole2.py", line 112, in <module>
        dev=str(matrix_assing(a, b))
    
      File "C:\Users\Pifko\dp\pigeon_hole2.py", line 13, in matrix_assing
        horizontalne = a[i][: len(a[i]) - i]
    
    IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

the output should be:

```
11 100
12 200
13 300
14 400 
15 500
25 600
35 700

21 200
22 300
23 400
24 500
34 600

31 300
32 400
33 500
```

If the matrix has 4 or more rows it works

example

```
 a = np.array([[11, 12, 13, 14,15,16,17],
                  [21, 22, 23, 24,25,26,27],
                  [31, 32, 33, 34,35,36,37],
                  [41, 42, 43, 44,45,46,47]])
```

output:

```
11 100
12 200
13 300
14 400
24 500
34 600
44 700

21 200
22 300
23 400
33 500
43 600

31 300
32 400
42 500
41 400
```

this is how it works properly

Can anyone help me with this error?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line
`for i in range(len(a[0])):` to

```
for i in range(min(len(a[0]), len(a[:,0]))):
```

?